# Por que char.Parse(string) retorna um número?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio, char

Estou fazendo um programa que usa typecast, mas quando converti uma string para char (`char.Parse()`), recebi o seguinte retorno: `115's'`

Qual é o motivo da conversão de *string* para char retornar um número na frente?

[image: Saída da conversão]

Comment: A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.parse?view=netcore-3.1) diz que a função retorna um caractere unicode. [O que pode ser considerado um caractere?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253557/100416) pode te ajudar a entender melhor sobre o assunto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método [`char.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.parse?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) existe basicamente para converter um caractere de uma `string` em um dado do tipo `char` da forma mais simples possível.

Esse método retorna o caractere que existe dentro da `string`. Essa `string` não pode ter mais que um caractere, caso contrário dá erro. Então se você tem um `"A"`, passará ter um `'A'`. Note os delimitadores que usei, é o mesmo caractere mas de tipos diferentes. É como se tivesse um número 1 com `short`, ou como `int` ou como `long`, todos são o número 1 mas os tipos do dado são diferentes.

A função não retorna 115, retorna só o `s` mesmo, o Visual Studio está te mostrando um número auxiliar equivalente desse caractere, no caso é um código ASCII ou Unicode. Esse dado é só para ajudar, o que interessa é o caractere `s`, pode ser que seu contexto tenha alguma serventia saber o número, mas é menos comum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).