# Como funcionaria um algoritmo para prevenir tentativas de enganar bloqueios de palavras (strings)?

Tags: string, algoritmo

Digamos eu desenvolva uma aplicação que permita a criação de registros arbitrários (não importa o assunto). No entanto, por alguma razão, decido bloquear a utilização da palavra `batata` no título do registro.

No entanto, o usuário pode, ao invés de utilizar `batata`, colocar `bat@t@`. Desse jeito, assumindo que o bloqueio seja implementado levianamente, como através de simples comparação de igualdade, nenhum erro ocorrerá — isto é, o bloqueio terá sido evitado. O usuário terá criado um registro (com a *ideia de palavra* que bloqueei, mas não exatamente igual à string que bloqueei).

Uma outra opção seria utilizar o caractere [ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) entre qualquer caractere da palavra, de modo a também burlar uma comparação leviana.

```js
const batata = 'batata';
const fakeBatata = 'bat' + '\u200B' + 'ata';

console.log(batata, fakeBatata); // Parecem iguais.
console.log(batata === fakeBatata); // Mas são diferentes.
```

Em relação ao caractere ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B), a solução que penso é relativamente simples, mas não ideal para todos os cenários. Bastaria bloquear qualquer utilização desse tipo de caractere (através de um *blacklist*, por exemplo). No entanto, não poderia bloquear um `@`, por exemplo, já que pode ser útil em alguns títulos.

Eu realmente não consigo pensar em um bom jeito de resolver esse problema. Também não sei o nome "formal" do problema e nem do hipotético algoritmo que amenize o problema.

É sequer possível resolver isso de forma eficiente? Se sim, como funcionaria o algoritmo?

---

<sup>Não faço questão de um algoritmo implementado, mas sim de uma orientação. No entanto, *além* da descrição acima, uma implementação (simples, se for um problema muito complexo) em alguma linguagem como JavaScript ou Python seria de ajuda também. :)</sup>

Comment: Provvelmente tem uma espécie de dicionário ou então uma série de regras comuns baseadas nos bloqueios, não precisa nem ser algo tão sofisticado ou matematicamente elaborado, um replace em `\u200B` já resolveria, o use de @ como A também, e assim por diante. Creio que não existe uma algoritimo especifico, deve ter uma série de "ideias" e sugestões, mas é dificil afirmar que sirva de regra.

Comment: Remover (ou bloquear) o `\u200B` até vai, mas bloquear (ou dar um _replace_) em caracteres especiais como o `@` não é ideal porque eles podem ser necessários em títulos legítimos.

Comment: O remover que cito é para testar e não para gravar. Substituir na hora e analisar a similaridade da palavra.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi errado. Realmente, é um pouco menos pior do que tinha pensado no quesito gravação. :)

Comment: Em PHP por exemplo já tem duas implementações de teste de similaridade https://www.php.net/levenshtein e https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php, mas mesmo com certos algoritimos algumas palavras tem que ser tratadas antes de avaliar.

Comment: Se a aplicação aceita um ZWS já me parece bug, pra começo de conversa. O set de caracteres teoricamente deveria ser restrito à natureza de um campo. Em línguas orientais é um pouco mais complicado, mas em ocidentais, não tem sentido aceitar sequer caracteres especiais comuns (um nome próprio no Brasil é a-z espaços e algumas letras acentuadas só, por exemplo. nem numerais pode. empresas podem ter o & e numerais, "-" e não muito mais que isso. O buraco é bem mais embaixo do que a pergunta está abrangendo. Bibliotecas como a ICU tem soluções prontas para isso, assim como Iconv.

Comment: Só não coloco como resposta pois tem um monte de furos: `let batata = 'Datilografia';
let fakeBatata = 'Ⓓati' + '\u200B' + 'lografia';
b = batata.replace(/\p{C}/ugi,'');
fB = fakeBatata.replace(/\p{C}/ugi,'');
console.log(b, fB); 
console.log(b.normalize('NFKC') == fB.normalize('NFKC'));`

Comment: Aliás, ao contrário do que os acólitos pregam, usar iso-8859-1, win-1252 (ou um subset destes, quase iguais) para software ocidental praticamente só traz vantagens (tem que conhecer o caso real, é óbvio - não tem bala de prata, nem solução universal). Aliás, DBs como MySQL/MariaDB permitem até que você especifique charsets diferentes em cada coluna, bem versátil para quem sabe o que está fazendo (que infelizmente, em termos de codificação de caracteres é uma minoria - para muitos, é praticamente um tabu esse assunto, por falta de ser dada a devida importância em fontes de aprendizado)

Comment: Eu usaria um algoritimo de score que vai dar uma nota para a semelhança das palavras. https://itsallbinary.com/similar-strings-or-same-sounding-strings-algorithms-comparison-apache-implementation-in-java/#fuzzy Não sei se é algo simples de implementar, mas certamente é melhor do que fazer uma blocklist gigantesca ou um regex enorme pra prevenir isso.

Comment: @LuizFelipe de uma olhada https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/WNowbqK?editors=1112 ,não é infalível mas ajuda.

Comment: Curiosamente: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359283/401803

Answer (score 1):

> Não é uma solução definitiva **pois acredito** que se tratando de Unicode
> essa solução não exista.

É possível restringir até certo grau as possibilidades do usuário de inserir combinações de caracteres para burlar restrições de palavras. Mas não o impedir totalmente, a mente humana é fértil quando se trata de burlar limites.

Nesse raciocínio imaginei o seguinte:

- Uma lista de palavras restritas e suas versões espelhadas.
- Pesquisar o [banco de dados de caracteres Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) em busca dos caracteres [homógrafos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) aos [caracteres ASCII](https://www.itscj.ipsj.or.jp/iso-ir/006.pdf) de `[A-Z]` incluindo `@`.
- Em uma entrada fornecida pelo usuário mapear os caracteres homógrafos para seus correspondentes ASCII.
- Passar a entrada mapeada e normalizada por um software de comparação aproximada para encontrar possíveis correspondências na lista de palavras restritas.

O algoritmo implementando esse exercício de pensamento foi realizado em python apoiado sobre os [relatórios técnicos Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/reports/).

---

```py
import unicodedata
import string
import difflib

#Essa função retorna uma lista de caracteres homógrafos a letter.
def homografos(letter):
    d = []                                                     #Inicializa a lista que receberá os caracteres homógrafos a letter. 
    #Hack para inserir o caractere @ caso solicitado no DB Unicode suas variantes estão discriminado como COMMERCIAL.
    if letter == "@":                                 
        letter = "COMMERCIAL"
    #Para todos os code points no DB Unicode...
    for i in range(0x10FFFF):
        l = chr(i)                                            #...obtem o caractere correspondente ao code point i.
        #...se letter estiver contido na descrição textual do code point em questão...
        if letter in unicodedata.name(l ,"None").split(" "):
            d.append(l)                                       #...adiciona o caractere correspondente ao code point i a lista de homógrafos a letter.
    return d                                                  #Retorna a lista de homógrafos a letter.

#Essa função faz a transliteração entre caracteres homógrafos
def transhomografos(letters):
    d={}                                              #Inicializa o dicionário de transliteração. O formato é mesmo usado por static str.maketrans(x[, y[, z]])
    print("Criando tabela de transliteração...")      #Para diminuir a ansiedade da espera.
    #Para cada caractere em letters...
    for c in letters:
        #...para cada caractere homográfo a c...
        for h in homografos(c):
            d[ord(h)] = ord('A' if c == "@" else c)   #...monta o dicionário de transliteração. Hack para traduzir @ para A.
        print(c)                                      #...para diminuir a ansiedade da espera.
    return d                                          #Retorna o dicionário de transliteração.
        
t = transhomografos(string.ascii_uppercase + '@')     #Cria em t o dicionário de transliteração de [A..Z@]incluindo @.

#Cria a lista de palavras restritas inclusive suas versões espelhadas.
restritas = []    
for p in ['batata', 'capim', 'feno']:
    restritas.append(p.upper())
    restritas.append(p.upper()[::-1])
    
while True:
   #Normaliza a entrada do usuário.
   p = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC',input("Digite uma palavra: "))
   #Se a entrada estiver vazia abandona o program.
   if not len(p):
       break
   p = p.translate(t)                                    #Traduz a entrada do usuário para seu equivalente ASCII.
   m = difflib.get_close_matches(p, restritas)           #Obtem a comparação aproximada entre a entrada tratada do usuário e a lista de palavras restritas.
   #Se a houver alguma semelhança exibe uma mensagem. 
   if len(m):
       print('Possivel palavra restrita encontrada',m)
```

Teste o exemplo no [Repli.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/UnicodeFilter#main.py).

Mais informações:

[Qual a diferença entre code page, plane, code point, octet e outros termos sobre caracteres?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394834/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-code-page-plane-code-point-octet-e-outros-termos-sobre)

[O que pode ser considerado um caractere?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253557/o-que-pode-ser-considerado-um-caractere/253706#253706)

Comment: Nossa, Augusto, não vi a sua resposta. Só reparei agora com a notificação do fim da recompensa... :( Como é a mais realista das respostas, eu provavelmente teria dado a recompensa. Uma pena ter desperdiçado.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit**: alterei quase todo o comportamento da classe*

Gostei do desafio que isso traz e fiz uma classe que gera dinamicamente uma regra em `regex` com todas as possibilidades combinadas entre os itens da **blacklist** e **cheats** e, por fim, filtra todos os caracteres `unicodes`.

O motivo de preferir `regex` e não um `"grau de similaridade"`, é por comparar "**batata**" com "**barata**"... Para resolver isso, seria necessário criar uma blacklist e whitelist ou diminuir a porcentagem de threshold, onde a complexidade poderia ser muito maior.

Com um regex dinâmico, adicionando `batata` na blacklist, a regra gerada é:

```regex
/(b.?|3.?|8.?)(a.?|@.?|4.?|á.?|à.?|â.?|ã.?|ª.?|^.?)(t.?|7.?)(a.?|@.?|4.?|á.?|à.?|â.?|ã.?|ª.?|^.?)(t.?|7.?)(a|@|4|á|à|â|ã|ª|^)/gim
```

**Dá match:** `b\u200Bát@74`, `bbaattaattaa`, `b@t@t@`, `347474`, `b a t a t a`, `b$a$t$a$t$a`, etc.

**Não dá match:** `barata`, `baratata`, etc.

> **Sobre Unicode:**
>
> Após várias tentativas, todas falhas, criei uma regra, também usando
> regex, para filtrar todo caractere Unicode ou que não respeite a regra
> de um caractere "comum" (`ß`, , `ɐʇɐʇɐ`).
>
> - A função `.normalize('NFKC')` consegue transcodificar alguns caracteres unicode, mas infelizmente, muita coisa passa batido.

**Como usar:**

```js
const blacklist = new Blacklist(_sua_blacklist_);
blacklist.validate('_string_a_ser_validada_');
```

**Como funciona:**

- Ao criar a classe, basta incluir sua blacklist (*array*) no construtor, com isso, serão geradas todas as regras em `regex` e guardadas na memória.
- Chamando a função `.validate()`, basta passar a string a ser validada. O retorno da função será, em caso de match, um objeto com as propriedades `matchs` e `Unicodes`:

```js
 {
  matchs: [
    'batata',
    'bbaattaatta',
    'b@t@t@'
    '347474',
    'b a t a t a',
    'b$a$t$a$t$a'
  ],
  unicodes: [ '', 'ɐʇɐʇɐ', 'ß' ]
}
```

Ou no caso de não ter nenhuma ocorrência (nem `matchs`, nem `unicodes`): **`true`**

> É possível adicionar desde palavras isoladas até expressões completas na blacklist, por exemplo, você permite `batata` e `purê` separadamente, mas se a pessoa inserir **`purê de batata`**, você quer bloquear.

A ideia ao retornar um objeto com todos os valores inválidos separados por "comuns" e "unicodes", é que para quem utilizar, poderá fazer seu próprio tratamento especifíco para cada situação. Seja um `replace(x, y)`, ou um **alerta ao usuário devolvendo todas as palavras e caracteres inválidos**.

A classe está pronta para ser utilizada, mas está bem comentada para auxiliar quem queira adaptar. Também deixei o código bem mais simples que antes e, ao fim do script, coloquei alguns exemplos na prática:

```js
class Blacklist {

   constructor(blacklist) {

      const cheats = {

         "a": [ "@", "4", "á", "à", "â", "ã", "ª", "^" ],
         "b": [ "3", "8" ],
         "c": [ "ç", "\\(", "\\[", "\\{", "<" ],
         "d": [ ],
         "e": [ "3", "é", "ê", "&" ],
         "f": [ ],
         "g": [ "6" ],
         "h": [ ],
         "i": [ "1", "!", "í", "l" ],
         "j": [ ],
         "k": [ ],
         "l": [ "1", "!", "í", "i" ],
         "m": [ "ññ", "nn" ],
         "n": [ "ñ" ],
         "o": [ "0", "ó", "ô", "õ", "º", "\\(\\)" ],
         "p": [ ],
         "q": [ ],
         "r": [ ],
         "s": [ "5", "\\$", "z" ],
         "t": [ "7" ],
         "u": [ "ú", "v", "w" ],
         "v": [ "u", "ú" ],
         "w": [ ],
         "x": [ ],
         "y": [ "i", "l" ],
         "z": [ "2", "s" ]
      };

      /* -- CODE -- */
      try {

         // valida a blacklist enviada
         if (!Array.isArray(blacklist)) throw('A blacklist precisa ser um array');

         // captura tudo que for unicode
         const getUnicode = /(((?!\s)(?=([^a-z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_+`'"=:{}[%?|;,./<>ªºáãàâéêíóõôºúüçñ\]\\\-\s]))).?(?=[^\x2A\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A])*)+/gim;
         // guarda os regex gerados com o conteúdo da blacklist
         const blacklistRegex = [];

         if (blacklist.length > 0) {

            // tratar itens da blacklist
            blacklist.map((item, id) => blacklist[id] = item.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\s\u0300-\u036f]/gim, '').toLowerCase());

            // percorre todos os itens da blacklist e cria um regex para cada um
            blacklist.forEach(item => {

               // "explode" cada caractere para um array
               const item_split = item.split('');
               
               // prepara variáveis para o loop
               let count = 0;
               let item_regex = '';
         
               // percorre cada caractere e cria um regex para cada combinação do objeto "cheat" no caractere relacionado
               item_split.forEach(character => {
         
                  count++;
                  const currentCheat = cheats[character];
                  
                  if (currentCheat) {

                     const item_length = item_split.length;
                     const cheat_length = currentCheat.length;

                     const regex_character = currentCheat.toString().split(',').join('.?|');
                     const regex_last_character = currentCheat.toString().split(',').join('|');

                     const cheatMid = cheat_length > 0 ? `|${regex_character}.?` : '';
                     const cheatLast = cheat_length > 0 ? `|${regex_last_character}` : '';

                     item_regex += count < item_length ? `(${character}.?${cheatMid})` : `(${character}${cheatLast})`;
                  }
               });
         
               // guarda na memória o regex final gerado pelo loop
               blacklistRegex.push(RegExp(item_regex, 'gim'));
            });
         }

         this.validate = text => {

            try {

               // valida os parâmetros
               if (typeof text !== 'string' || text?.trim().length === 0) throw('O conteúdo a ser validado precisa ser do tipo string');
               if (blacklist.length === 0) return true;
               
               // normalizar dígitos (como "\u0061" de volta para "a")
               text = text.normalize('NFC');
               // remover espaços duplicados
               text = text.replace(/\s/gim, ' ');
               
               // guarda, caso ocorra, os "matchs" com os itens da blacklist
               const invalids = [];
               // guarda, caso ocorra, os caracteres unicodes
               const unicodes = text.match(getUnicode) || [];
            
               // verifica ocorrências para cada regex gerado
               blacklistRegex.forEach(regex => {
            
                  // cria um array com as ocorrências, caso houver
                  const words = text.match(regex);
            
                  if (words?.length > 0) Object.assign(invalids, words);
               });
               
               return invalids?.length > 0 || unicodes?.length > 0 ? { matchs: invalids, unicodes: unicodes } : true;
            }
            catch(error) {

               console.error(error);
            }
         };
      }
      catch(error) {

         console.error(error);
      }
   }
}


/***********\
|  TESTING  |
\***********/

const myBlacklist = [ 'batata' ];
const blacklist = new Blacklist(myBlacklist);

const invalid = blacklist.validate( 'b\u200Bát@74 | bátátá | b$at$a$t$a | 347474 |  | ɐʇɐʇɐq | b a t a t a | b-a-t-a-t-a | ß @ 7 @ 7 @ | bbaattaattaa' );
const valid = blacklist.validate( 'Nada a ser encontrado por aqui' );

console.log('FALSO: \n', invalid);
console.log('VERDADEIRO: \n', valid);
```

*Espero que ajude e, indiretamente, obrigado pela ideia.*

Comment: Nenhum código detector de palavras rasuradas funciona com Unicode. Se eu escrever `` todos falham. Se quiser tentar eu escrevi [esse teste](https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/WNowbqK?editors=1112) que faz a comparação fuzzy é o que funciona melhorzinho, mas tem muitos furos.

Comment: Legal mas são 65535 formas de escrever `ɐʇɐʇɐq` com Unicode.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, obrigado pelo "report". Editei o código para ele entender o `` também. No objeto `cheats`, é possível adicionar quantos Unicodes fossem possíveis, mas realmente essas "65535 formas" se tornaram um problema. Adicionei isso como o principal "contra" na resposta, enquanto penso em uma forma de resolver isso.

Comment: Uma amostra de b̶̨̪͍̥̗̬̈́̌̓̐̾̄̐̃̂̀̉̚͠ą̴̘̮͕͙̰̬͕͉̘͖̠̇̓̍͗͂͑̈̆̊̽̆̈̋̆͒̋͆̕̕̚͠͝ţ̵̡̦̜̳̝̹͎̮̬͔̰̻̤̩͔̥̯̠̯̩̻̩̃̉̉͌͜a̵̡̡̛͖͇̪̤͂̈́͛͗̂̎̈́̒̈́̑̔̈̀̄͛͂̄̃̔͐͌̈́̕̕͝͝ṫ̵̲̠̻͚̫̣͇̜͖͔̰̥̦̾͐̓͆̇̒͌̓̓́͐̃̇̐͗̉̓̃̔̋̕̕͜͝ͅa̴̩̟͇̲͉̙͈̙͊̒̿͑̇͆̽̓͋̈̊̃̍̃̂̐̉̿͌̑̔͐̕͘͠  b̴̧͉͖̥̰̤̟̱͕̬͙͓̬̘̀͊̿̉̌̕ä̸̡͖̠̮̪̻̝̞̥̤́̀̍́͋͘͘t̷̢͖̜͇̜̰̬͕͌̒̽͋́̈́͛̚̚ä̸̮̼̫͍̯́̃̃̎͊͗t̸̲̤͚̘͗͑̉͘ả̸̡͇̺̟͇̭͕͛̔͑̀͗̅̇͘͠ b̵̭̲̲̋̇́̓͒̾̚̕ͅą̴̨̗̹͕̻̜̱͐̄̓̂̑̎̑͜t̴͕̲̤̗̩͈̼̖̻͌͐̉͗̾͋̾̓̆͆a̷̧̲̯̦̲̜͛̔̾͂̋̍t̷̢̩͛͂̊̂͌a̸̭̝͙̦̗̼͑̀̔̓̋̐͘ b̴̯̳͂a̵̢̝̝͑͊̆͊̐ț̴̞͐̊͌̌̃͜å̵̦̒t̸͉̟̮̂͆a̸̬̔́̐̎̅ b̶̪̃̀̈a̷͉̻͚̎t̴̝͇̱͛̔â̶̩̲t̸͔͊̔ã̶̝̩ b̶̻͍̍̚a̴̝̖̋̑ẗ̴͚͕å̵̳̈t̷̜̱́a̷̺̬̚   乃ᗩαţᗩ   

Comment: ｂａｔａｔａ ʙᴀᴛᴀᴛᴀ ɐʇɐʇɐq  ɒƚɒƚɒd  bₐₜₐₜₐ ᵇᵃᵗᵃᵗᵃ ⓑⓐⓣⓐⓣⓐ ๒คՇคՇค Ⴆαƚαƚα ɮǟȶǟȶǟ ᏰᏗᏖᏗᏖᏗ ცąɬąɬą ๖คtคtค     BΛƬΛƬΛ вαтαтα ßå†å†å ฿₳₮₳₮₳ 乃卂ㄒ卂ㄒ卂 乃ﾑｲﾑｲﾑ【b】【a】【t】【a】【t】【a】『b』『a』『t』『a』『t』『a』≋b≋a≋t≋a≋t≋a≋ ░b░a░t░a░t░a░ [̲̅b][̲̅a][̲̅t][̲̅a][̲̅t][̲̅a] b҉a҉t҉a҉t҉a҉
ҍąէąէą ᗷᗩTᗩTᗩ ᗷᗩᖶᗩᖶᗩ b̶a̶t̶a̶t̶a̶ b̴a̴t̴a̴t̴a̴ b̷a̷t̷a̷t̷a̷ b̾a̾t̾a̾t̾a̾ b͎a͎t͎a͎t͎a͎ b͓̽a͓̽t͓̽a͓̽t͓̽a͓̽

Comment: @AugustoVasques, realizei uma tratativa totalmente diferente com relação aos unicodes e editei quase que totalmente a resposta. Tentando sair da caixa, parece ser impossível um método de dar match com todas as variações de unicode possíveis, então ao invés disso, **fiz com que o código "dedure" os caracteres que ele não consegue lidar**, para um tratamento posterior ao match e, não durante, como estava. Se puder, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Ainda seguindo a ideia do unicode, da maneira atual, a pessoa pode escolher, por exemplo, substituir todas as ocorrências "normais" por algo como " [ editado ] ", enquanto com relação aos unicodes, substituir por "" (vazio). Procurei isso por muito tempo (bem antes dessa pergunta) e nada me atendeu, mas nunca tinha parado pra tentar. Não pretendo mais mexer nesse código por aqui, mas da maneira como está agora, me sinto mais confiante para adaptar nos meus projetos reais. A ideia era ajudar e acabei me ajudando.

Comment: Eu acabei de ver, é que estou tentando lhe falar o problema é insolúvel. O objetivo desse código é criar algo tipo um **bot family safety** para o chats(facebook, tweeter, instagram, discord, twich, whatsapp,..), filtrando palavrões em conversas e usuários com apelidos obscenos mas permitir que palavras comuns possam ser usadas mesmo que rasuradas

Answer (score -2):

Eu começaria implementando distância Levenshtein para ver se resolve o problema (se é que eu entendi bem o que você pretende fazer).

Em Python por exemplo o NLTK tem muita coisa que pode te ajudar a fazer isso. Inclusive pronto já. Mas vc acha implementações de distância Levenshtein em qualquer linguagem. É simples.

com poucas linhas é possível fazer o cálculo da distância de duas palavras. Obviamente você precisa ter o dicionário das palavras que você pretende bloquear. Senão como o seu software vai "adivinhar" isso?

Então, basta considerar abaixo o array "palavras" como sendo um dicionário de palavras que vc deseja bloquear.

```
import nltk

proibido = "b@t@t@"
palavras = ['batata', 'bota', 'borracha', 'b@t@t@', 'outro']

for p in palavras:
    dist = nltk.edit_distance(proibido, p)
    print(p, dist)
```

Resultado do cálculo de distância:

```
batata 3
bota 4
borracha 7
b@t@t@ 0
outro 5
```

Comment: Por favor, quem "downvotar" explique o motivo nos comentários, pois para mim está muito claro que essa solução funciona pois já precisei fazer isso. A não ser que eu tenha entendido errado a pergunta.Mesma coisa com o novato ali o Luiz Felipe. (é chato receber um downvote) e não saber o motivo para poder melhorar.

Comment: Nenhum código detector de palavras rasuradas funciona com Unicode. Se eu escrever `` todos falham. Se quiser tentar eu escrevi [esse teste](https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/WNowbqK?editors=1112) que faz a comparação fuzzy é o que funciona melhorzinho, mas tem muitos furos. PS: Nem votei pois eu acho essa questão insolúvel.