# Como estilizar a tag fieldset usando atributo id?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar um `{background-color: aqua;}` na tag fieldset, usando `id="003"` e endereçando o estilo para o arquivo externo .CSS. Mas não está acontecendo alteração nenhuma. Quando eu escrevo no arquivo HTML: fieldset `style="background-color:aqua;"` ai funciona. Mas deveria estar funcionando da forma que eu escrevi abaixo também.

<--! No arquivo HTML: linha 2 -->

```
<form action="/formulario.html" target="_blank">
     <fieldset id="003">
        <legend>Formulario Agrupado:</legend>
        Email:<br/>
        <input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
        Senha:<br/>
        <input name="senha" type="password"><br/>
        Idade:<br/>
        <select>
           <option>opção 01</option>
           <option>opção 02</option>
           <option>opção 03</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        Sexo:<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="m"/> Masculino
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="f"/> Feminino<br/>
        Redes Sociais:<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="redes" value="facebook"/> Facebook
        <input type="checkbox" name="redes" value="google"/> Google<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
     </fieldset>
  </form>
```

<--! No arquivo CSS: -->

```
#003{background-color: aqua;}
```

Comment: O id não pode começar com um número.

Comment: Leitura recomendada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253484/%C3%89-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica-colocar-n%C3%BAmeros-como-id-em-elementos-html-se-sim-por-qu%C3%AA?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o que diz a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) no MDN acerca do atributo `id`:

> **Nota:** Utilizar caracteres exceto letras e dígitos ASCII, '_', '-' e '.' pode causar problemas de compatibilidade, já que eles não eram
>   permitidos no HTML 4. Embora esta restrição fora suspensa no HTML 5,
>   um ID deve iniciar com uma letra para fins de compatibilidade.

Ou seja, um `id` deve começar com uma letra. No seu caso está começando com um número.

Adicionando qualquer letra ao início do seu `id`, irá funcionar. veja:

```css
#a003{background-color: aqua;}
```

```html
<form action="/formulario.html" target="_blank">
     <fieldset id="a003">
        <legend>Formulario Agrupado:</legend>
        Email:<br/>
        <input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
        Senha:<br/>
        <input name="senha" type="password"><br/>
        Idade:<br/>
        <select>
           <option>opção 01</option>
           <option>opção 02</option>
           <option>opção 03</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        Sexo:<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="m"/> Masculino
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="f"/> Feminino<br/>
        Redes Sociais:<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="redes" value="facebook"/> Facebook
        <input type="checkbox" name="redes" value="google"/> Google<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
     </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: entendi.
 Desleixo da minha parte com um erro bobo desse rs. 
Funcionou agora, obrigado pela ajuda !