# ID com o primeiro caractere sendo um número não funciona quando coloco no css #[número de exemplo]

Tags: html5, css3

Quando por exemplo coloco no HTML:`<div id="1">texto de teste</div>` e vou colocar no CSS: `#1 {código de teste}`, não reconhece o `id=1`. Mesmo se eu colocar "class" no lugar do "id", ou se eu colocar outra tag, ou colocar outro número. Isso é um problema do meu código? Ou é normal? Por que isso acontece?

Comment: @Augusto VasquesEntão por que eu não consigo utilizar um número no começo de um `id`? Sendo que não há restrição. Eu já verifiquei inúmeras vezes se não era um problema de falta de **;** _ou_ **{** , ou qualquer outra coisa. Simplesmente não funciona. Se você sabe o que está acontecendo me ajuda, por favor :D. Valeu!

Comment: É só compatibilidade mesmo?

Comment: @GiovanePS olhe a parte final da minha resposta que trata especificamente de *CSS*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a recomendação *W3C* de 28 de outubro de 2014, [HTML5
Um vocabulário e APIs associadas para HTML e XHTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#the-id-attribute), está regulamentando:

> 3.2.5.1 O atributo `id`
>
> O atributo `id` especifica o identificador exclusivo (ID) do seu elemento.
>
> O valor deve ser exclusivo entre todos os `IDs` na subárvore inicial
>   do elemento e deve conter ao menos um caractere. O valor não deve
>   conter caracteres de espaço.
>
> *Não há outras restrições* sobre a forma que um `ID` pode assumir, em particular os `IDs` podem consistir apenas em dígitos, começar com um
>   dígito, começar com um sublinhado, consistir apenas em pontuação etc.
>
> O identificador exclusivo de um elemento pode ser usado para uma
>   variedade de propósitos, principalmente como uma maneira de vincular
>   partes específicas de um documento usando identificadores de
>   fragmentos, como uma maneira de direcionar um elemento ao criar
>   scripts e como uma maneira de estilizar um elemento específico. *CSS*.
>
> Identificadores são cadeias opacas. Significados particulares não
>   devem ser derivados do valor do atributo `id`.

O que claramente confirma que você não cometeu nenhuma violação em seu código HTML, mas dando uma olhada na documentação [MDN sobre Ids](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) há uma uma nota recomendatória:

> **Nota**: Utilizar caracteres exceto letras e dígitos ASCII, '_', '-' e '.' pode causar problemas de compatibilidade, já que eles não eram
>   permitidos no HTML 4. Embora esta restrição fora suspensa no HTML 5,
>   **um ID deve iniciar com uma letra para fins de compatibilidade**.

Essa recomendação de que **um ID deve iniciar com uma letra para fins de compatibilidade** é bastante significativa pois segundo as recomendações:

- [WC3 Selectors Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#id-selectors)
- [WC3 Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#characters)

> No CSS, os identificadores (incluindo nomes de elementos, classes e
>   IDs nos seletores ) podem conter apenas os caracteres [a-zA-Z0-9] e os
>   caracteres ISO 10646 U + 00A0 e superior, além do hífen (-) e o
>   sublinhado ( _); **eles não podem começar com um dígito, dois hífens ou
>   um hífen seguido por um dígito**. Os identificadores também podem conter
>   caracteres de escape e qualquer caractere ISO 10646 como um código
>   numérico (consulte o próximo item). Por exemplo, o identificador
>   "P&B?" pode ser escrito como "B \ & W \?" ou "B \ 26 W \ 3F".

Tendo por consequência que seu `id` iniciado por um número é compatível com o *HTML5* porém não é compatível com o *CSS* e por isso não é reconhecido.

Quanto a questão de ser má pratica utilizar identificadores explicitamente numéricos sim eu concordo com a recomendação feita nos comentários da questão [É uma má prática colocar números como id em elementos HTML? Se sim por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253484/%C3%89-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica-colocar-n%C3%BAmeros-como-id-em-elementos-html-se-sim-por-qu%C3%AA)