# pegar todos getElementsByClassName com class exatamente igual

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de pagar todas as div que contenham exatamente as class '1 2 3' Exemplo.

```
<div data-full="true" class="1 2 3 4">
    <div class="1 2 3">text</div>
</div>
<div class="1 2 3">text</div>
<div class="1 2 3">text</div>
<div data-full="true" class="1 2 3 4">
   <div class="1 2 3">text</div>
</div>
```

Porem preciso que ele ignore nesse caso a primeira div e seus filhos e a ultima div e seus filho.
todas as div pai tem o elemento data-full="true"
eu tentei anteriormente usar o java script assim porem ele selecionas todas

```
var teste = document.querySelectorAll('.1.2.3');
for (var i=0, len=teste.length|0; i<len; i=i+1|0) {
    console.log(teste[i]);
}
```

conforme o link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
porem nao funcionou com meus testes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias opções:

```js
console.log('Modo 1')

for (const el of document.body.querySelectorAll(':not([data-full]) > [class="n1 n2 n3"]'))
  console.log(el);

console.log('Modo 2')

for (const el of document.body.querySelectorAll(':not([data-full]) > .n1.n2.n3:not(.n4)'))
  console.log(el);
 
console.log('Modo 3')

for (const el of document.body.querySelectorAll(':not([data-full]) > .n1.n2.n3:not([data-full])'))
  console.log(el);
```

```html
<div data-full="true" class="n1 n2 n3 n4">
    <div class="n1 n2 n3">text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="n1 n2 n3">text 2</div>
<div class="n3 n2 n1">text 3</div>
<div data-full="true" class="n1 n2 n3 n4">
   <div class="n1 n2 n3">text 4</div>
</div>
```

A ideia é pegar os elementos com as classes desejadas, que não seja precedido diretamente (`>`) por um elemento com o atributo `data-full`

- Modo 1 `[class="n1 n2 n3"]`: você pode usar o seletor de atributo para buscar por um elemento com a classe exata, porém, nesse caso a ordem é importante, observe que no exemplo um dos elementos do meio não foi selecionado, já que a ordem das classes está bagunçada
- Modo 2 `.n1.n2.n3:not(.n4)`: pega os que tiver as classes n1, n2 e n3 e que não tenha a classe n4, nesse caso a ordem não importa
- Modo 3 `.n1.n2.n3:not([data-full])`: pega os que tiver as classes n1, n2 e n3 e que não tenha o atributo `data-full`, caso esse atributo sempre esteja presente junto com a classe n4

Comment: Cara eu não imaginava que daria para usar esses pseudo-seletor de CSS tipo `:not()` dentro do JS! Bem massa!

Answer (score 4):

Nome de classe um número não é interpretado corretamente. Evite usar nomes de classe ou mesmo de ID como `id="1`" ou `class="1"`, se quiser escreve por extenso, tipo `id="um"` ou `class="n1"` tb funciona.

Veja aqui: [ID com o primeiro caractere sendo um número não funciona quando coloco no css #[número de exemplo]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/425955/id-com-o-primeiro-caractere-sendo-um-n%C3%BAmero-n%C3%A3o-funciona-quando-coloco-no-css)

E aqui: [É uma má prática colocar números como id em elementos HTML? Se sim por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253484/%c3%89-uma-m%c3%a1-pr%c3%a1tica-colocar-n%c3%bameros-como-id-em-elementos-html-se-sim-por-qu%c3%aa)

Depois use um `forEach()` no lugar do `for`, acho que facilita a sintaxe, e tb utilize um `if` para validar o `className` e excluir o primeiro filho.

Veja como fica a sugestão

```js
const teste = document.querySelectorAll('.n1.n2.n3');

teste.forEach( (el) => {
  if (el.className === 'n1 n2 n3') {
    console.log(el);
  }
})
```

```html
<div data-full="true" class="n1 n2 n3 4">
  <div class="n1 n2 n3">text</div>
</div>
<div class="n1 n2 n3">text</div>
<div class="n1 n2 n3">text</div>
<div data-full="true" class="n1 n2 n3 4">
  <div class="n1 n2 n3">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dei essa resposta de forma simples, com código básico, mas acredito que uma resposta usando Array ou JSON seja mais adequada... só que não tenho conhecimento para tal 

Comment: Regex tb pode ser uma solução, mas tb não tenho conhecimento técnico 

Comment: Não sabia desse problema de começar por um número, mas também nunca pensei em usar um número... Vivendo e aprendendo